# Connection not successful: javax.jms.JMSException: User name [null] or password is invalid in wso2

Tags: activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-cep

I am trying to create an output event adaptor.

Adaptor type: jms

JNDI Initial Context Factory Class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

JNDI Provider URL : tcp://localhost:61616

Connection Factory JNDI Name : TopicConnectionFactory

when i provide user name and password and test the connection its showing

"Connection not successful: javax.jms.JMSException: User name [null] or password is invalid."

Can some one please suggest where i have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After starting ActiveMQ type the following via the terminal.

```
  $ netstat -an|grep 61616
```

The port should be opened and listening on 61616. You can also go to the following link and verify if you are able to log in.

http://localhost:8161/admin

If you are unable to then there is a problem in your connectivity. Refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM200/Installing+Apache+ActiveMQ+on+Linux) document to correctly install ACTIVEMQ on your machine. Stop and restart the server and try the above steps again. Also if possible please mention the version of the ACTIVEMQ you are currently using.